# Origin of the phrase "along for the ride"?

Tags: etymology

Please explain  where this phrase comes from.  What is the preposition "along" for?

***[along for the ride:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/along+for+the+ride)***

> Participating but not actively, as in Don't ask me how long this job will take; I'm just along for the ride. This metaphoric term often is preceded by just to emphasize the passive role of the "passenger." [Mid-1900s]

(AHD)

Comment: 'Along' can have the sense of 'accompanying others', as in 'Come along' = come with me/us.

Comment: I came to this site to ask about the idiom used in the second verse of "Toss a Coin to Your Witcher" but I'm going with this one. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently "along" was only added to the expression later. The Oxford English Dictionary lists the following quotes without *along*:

> Lily would like to go to the court-house this forenoon, just for the ride, you know, and I think the air and exercise will do her good.
>   <sub>[Husks](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=moa&cc=moa&view=text&rgn=main&idno=ADH6153.0001.001), 1863</sub>

> Large open sleighs drawn by four and sometimes six horses were resorted to, and many individuals and parties enjoyed these for the ride alone.
>   <sub>[Reminiscences of an Octogenarian of the City of New York](http://www.jmisc.net/octo/octo-24.htm), 1896</sub>

The earliest quote they have for ***along*** for the ride is 1951:

> I only went along for the ride, and to see what else Neal was going to do.
>   <sub>[On the road](https://books.google.com/books?id=Jr5jsdYci2EC&pg=PT215&lpg=PT215&dq=%22I+only+went+along+for+the+ride,+and+to+see+what+else+Neal+was+going+to+do.%22)</sub>

However, [searching Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22along+for+the+ride%22&tbs=sbd:1,cdr:1,cd_max:1955&tbm=bks&ei=QUmhW9qFEe7n5gLR07vIBg&start=0&sa=N&biw=1440&bih=687&dpr=1) brings earlier quotes such as the following quote from 1933:

> Who? Me, doc? You can't kill me. Anyway, I just went along for the ride.
>   <sub>[Boys' Life](https://books.google.com/books?id=qrSaLgwGkiEC&pg=PA33&dq=%22along+for+the+ride%22)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

*Phrase **go along for the ride** in the figurative sense "join in passively" is from 1956.* [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ride#etymonline_v_41075)

**along**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/along)

2. As company: Bring your friend along.

As in:

> I'm just along for the ride = I am joining the company for the
>   ride/adventure.

Comment: I would guess a lot older than that.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=along+for+the+ride&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calong%20for%20the%20ride%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

[Boys' Life 1933](https://books.google.com/books?id=qrSaLgwGkiEC&pg=PA33&dq=%22along+for+the+ride%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQt-q7ocXdAhWX3oMKHVXaBCsQuwUIRzAH#v=onepage&q=%22along%20for%20the%20ride%22&f=false):

> The last coherent thing that Danny heard after that was Drubb,
>   chuckling, actually chuckling, and saying: "Who?  Me, doc?  You can't
>   kill me.  Anyway, I just went along for the ride."

"Along for the ride" is a fairly literal expression, and likely has existed for hundreds of years.  It no doubt became more popular with the automobile (as [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=along+for+the+ride&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calong%20for%20the%20ride%3B%2Cc0) suggests).